# Mathematica to $\LaTeX$ in a for loop

Tags: latex

Hello I have a `For` loop which outputs an expression and I want to convert everything to $\LaTeX$ at once (not line by line). This is my code:

```
K[Q_, n_Integer] := 
 Module[{z, x}, 
  SymmetricReduction[
     SeriesCoefficient[
      Product[ComposeSeries[Series[Q[z], {z, 0, n}], 
        Series[x[i] z, {z, 0, n}]], {i, 1, n}], n], 
     Table[x[i], {i, 1, n}], Table[Subscript[c, i], {i, 1, n}]][[1]] //
    FactorTerms]

  poly = K[Sqrt[#]/Tanh[Sqrt[#]] &, 4] /. c -> p;
  primeFactorForm[n_] := 
  If[Length@# == 1, First@#, CenterDot @@ #] &[
  Superscript @@@ FactorInteger[n]];

  For[i = 0, i < 5, i++, 
  poly = K[Sqrt[#]/Tanh[Sqrt[#]] &, i] /. c -> p;  
  Print[Subscript[L, i], " = ", 
  Plus @@ List @@ Distribute[poly] /. 
  Times[Rational[n_, d_], e__] :> 
  primeFactorForm[n]/ primeFactorForm[d]*e]]
```

I am not sure how to convert all the 10 lines to $\LaTeX$. I tried some basic functions (`TeXForm` for example) but I get `\text{Null}`. Can someone help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: For a start, use `Table` instead of `For` and `Print`...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher getting the same result with Table

Comment: You get `\text{Null}` from `TexForm` because _you are still using `For` along with `Print` instead of `Table`_. `Print` and `For` are not meant for returning results; `Table` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to produce a string, that can be copied, e.g., to a $\LaTeX$ document, you may use the following. It is important to prevent `Set` (also known as `=`) from evaluation; turning it into a string "=" by hand is subobtimal since `TeXForm` will wrap it with `\text{=}`. That is why I use `Inactive` on the `InputForm` of `=`.

```
string = StringJoin["\\begin{gather}",
  Riffle[
   Table[
    poly = K[Sqrt[#]/Tanh[Sqrt[#]] &, i] /. c -> p;

    ToString[

     Inactive[Set][Subscript[L, i], 
      Plus @@ List @@ Distribute[poly] /. 
       Times[Rational[n_, d_], e__] :> primeFactorForm[n]/primeFactorForm[d]*e
      ],
     TeXForm
     ]
    ,
    {i, 0, 4}] ,
   "\\\\"
   ],
  "\n\\end{gather}"
  ]
```

$$\begin{gather}L_0=1\\L_1=p_1+\frac{1}{3}\\L_2=\frac{p_1^2 -1^1}{3^2\cdot 5^1}+\frac{p_2 7^1}{3^2\cdot 5^1}\\L_3=\frac{p_1^3 2^1}{3^3\cdot 5^1\cdot 7^1}+\frac{p_2 p_1 -1^1\cdot 13^1}{3^3\cdot 5^1\cdot 7^1}+\frac{p_3 2^1\cdot 31^1}{3^3\cdot 5^1\cdot 7^1}\\L_4=\frac{p_1^4 -1^1}{3^3\cdot 5^2\cdot 7^1}+\frac{p_2 p_1^2 2^1\cdot 11^1}{3^4\cdot 5^2\cdot 7^1}+\frac{p_3 p_1 -1^1\cdot 71^1}{3^4\cdot 5^2\cdot 7^1}+\frac{p_2^2 -1^1\cdot 19^1}{3^4\cdot 5^2\cdot 7^1}+\frac{p_4 127^1}{3^3\cdot 5^2\cdot 7^1}
\end{gather}$$

Note that special characters such as `"\"`, `"""`, and *newline* have to be replaced by appropriate escape sequences `"\\"`, `"\""`, and `\n`. Copying this with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> will most likely lead to errors. However, executing `CopyToClipboard[string]` (and then pasting <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> into any other editor) will work.

Comment: @Thank you for this. However when I try to copy it in a file text it doesn't work the way I want...

Comment: Silviu -- you need to specify how you want it to work. What part fails?

Comment: @Silviu I have edited the post. Have a look.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thank you for this, but it still doesn't work. I also edited my post adding the whole code that I want to convert into latex.

Comment: Thank you so so much for this!

Comment: You're welcome!